# How to hide column if roles not 'admin'

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

How to hide the Read, Update and Delete button column from other user. Only user with 'admin' roles can see the button. Every users has been assign either 'admin' or 'user' roles in database.

can hide the button from other user which not admin

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['salary'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo '<a href="read.php?id='. $row['id'] .'" class="mr-3" title="View Record" data-toggle="tooltip"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a>';
            echo '<a href="update.php?id='. $row['id'] .'" class="mr-3" title="Update Record" data-toggle="tooltip"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></a>';
            echo '<a href="delete.php?id='. $row['id'] .'" title="Delete Record" data-toggle="tooltip"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a>';
        echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you already save the user role in the database, you can check the condition using php like below

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $userRole = $row['role'];
   $traw = "<tr>";
        $traw .="<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
       $traw .="<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
        $traw .="<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
        $traw .="<td>" . $row['salary'] . "</td>";
        $traw .="<td >";
        if($userRole == 'admin') {
        $traw .='<a href="read.php?id='. $row['id'] .'" class="mr-3" title="View Record" data-toggle="tooltip"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a>':'';
        $traw .='<a href="update.php?id='. $row['id'] .'" class="mr-3" title="Update Record" data-toggle="tooltip"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></a>';
        $traw .='<a href="delete.php?id='. $row['id'] .'" title="Delete Record" data-toggle="tooltip"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a>';
         }
        $traw .= "</td>";
   $traw .="</tr>";

        echo $traw;
```

Comment: niceee its workss!!! thankss!! btw what the difference between $traw and 'echo'? im new in php html.

Comment: No.. I just assigned those td's and anchor tag's to one parameter and the echo the paraemter